# Pass initialValues to custom hook typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a hook useForm and wanted to use this in all forms
this close below is what I'm doing to pass initial values but it does not work
I'm new to typescript

```
interface IForm1 {
  name?: string;
  description?: string;
}
interface IForm2 {
  word?: string;
}

type FormTypes = IForm1 | IForm2;

const useForm = (initialState: FormTypes) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialState);
  return { values };
};

const work = () => {
  const [values] = useForm({
    word: '',
  });

  console.log(values.word);
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: Property 'word' does not exist on type 'IForm1 '.
Maybe I need to use generic in useForm
I'm new to typescript I Really don't know what I'm doing :D

Comment: FYI, that information should be added to the question by using the "edit" button. Regarding the error, that is to be expected. You have said either `IForm1` or `IForm2` and only one of them has `word`. Yes, you need a generic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make your hook a generic function in order to obtain the desired behavior.

```
interface IForm1 {
  name?: string;
  description?: string;
}
interface IForm2 {
  word?: string;
}

type FormTypes = IForm1 | IForm2;

const useForm = <T extends FormTypes>(initialState: T) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialState);
  return { values };
};
```

Additionally you need to change your return value to match your destructuring. If you plan to destructure the result as an array,`const [values] = useForm(...)`, then you need to return an array.

```
const useForm = <T extends FormTypes>(initialState: T) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialState);
  return [values];
};
```

Or, more concisely, if you don't mind returning the `setValues` capability to the caller

```
const useForm = <T extends FormTypes>(initialState: T) => useState(initialState);
```